# ObjectMapper deserialization with TypeReference without a concrete class

Tags: java, spring, jackson

I came across a following source code that I do not understand:

```
final Book book = objectMapper.readValue(string, new TypeReference<>() {
    });
```

How will Jackson understand what class to deserialize from the provided string?

I found a similar construct in [this article](https://northcoder.com/post/jackson-object-mapper-which-way-is/), where it is written it will throw an exception. But the code actually works and Book is deserialized. What is this black magic?

Comment: This mechanism is called type erasure, where the type parameter is available at runtime. https://www.baeldung.com/java-type-erasure

Comment: `TypeReference<>()` also uses "diamond" operator, which is short for `TypeReference<Book>()` in this case.

Comment: I see. A compiler will use Book from the assignment, correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a clever way to deal with Java Generics type erasure. From ["Type Erasure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html)

> To implement generics, the Java compiler applies type erasure to:
>
> - Replace all type parameters in generic types with their bounds or
>   Object if the type parameters are unbounded. The produced bytecode,
>   therefore, contains only ordinary classes, interfaces, and methods.
> - Insert type casts if necessary to preserve type safety.
> - Generate bridge methods to preserve polymorphism in extended generic types.

[Neil Gafter](http://www.gafter.com/%7Eneal/) refers to

```java
public abstract class TypeReference<T> {}
```

as *super type tokens*.

When you now do a

```java
TypeReference<Book> x = new TypeReference<Book>() {};
```

or in Neals [example](http://gafter.blogspot.com/2006/12/super-type-tokens.html)

```
TypeReference<List<String>> x = new TypeReference<List<String>>() {};
```

there is no type erasure happening for the anonymous class created on the right-hand-side of the assignment. It has a fixed generic type, which can be accessed by the super class like this:

```java
  protected TypeReference() {
        Type superclass = getClass().getGenericSuperclass();
        if (superclass instanceof Class) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Missing type parameter.");
        }
        this.type = ((ParameterizedType) superclass).getActualTypeArguments()[0];
    }
```

Jacksons `ObjectMapper` will use the `this.type` later to figure out the type of things you want to deserialise.

Observation of the diamond operator is ofc correct.